# Best Esperanto word for "music stand"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to find the best word to use for a music stand (the typically metal, often tripod like, stands for holding sheet music open for musicians to play from).

Several web pages I tried suggested **muzikportilo**, which I wasn't entirely convinced about and I've seen one example of **notstarilo** which equally didn't seem quite right.  Neither of these is present in the online *Vortaro* and I couldn't find much to indicate they were frequently used.

Then, after going extensively through the *Vortaro* I saw that the definition for **pupitro** specifically mentions musical scores:

> **pupitro 1:**
> Mebleto, prezentanta deklivon, sur kiun oni metas libron, kajeron, partituron, por pli oportune legi aŭ skribi.

So does this mean **muzikpupitro** would be a better description?  Are there any Esperantist musicians out there who could tell me what they use?

Comment: Laŭ mi *pupitro* estas jam tute priskriba. Sed se vi volas precizigi vi povas kunmeti ion kun *pupitro*. Mi preferus *partitur-*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jes, *Pupitro* estas la ĝusta vorto, ne vere bezonatas "muzik-"

Yes, *Pupitro* is the correct word, "muzik-" isn't really needed